# Drawing with text on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to implement **[this neat animation](http://codepen.io/tholman/full/qCnfB)**:

```
// Drawing with text. Ported from Generative Design book - http://www.generative-gestaltung.de - Original licence: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

// Application variables
var position = {x: 0, y: window.innerHeight/2};
var counter = 0;
var minFontSize = 14;
var angleDistortion = 0;
var letters = "En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que viv\xEDa un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, roc\xEDn flaco y galgo corredor. Una olla de algo m\xE1s vaca que carnero, salpic\xF3n las m\xE1s noches, duelos y quebrantos los s\xE1bados, lentejas los viernes, alg\xFAn palomino de a\xF1adidura los domingos, consum\xEDan las tres partes de su hacienda.";

// Drawing variables
var canvas;
var context;
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, down: false}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
  context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   mouseUp,   false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseout',  mouseUp,  false);  
  canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick, false);

  window.onresize = function(event) {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}

function mouseMove ( event ){
  mouse.x = event.pageX;
  mouse.y = event.pageY;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
 if ( mouse.down ) {
    var d = distance( position, mouse );
    var fontSize = minFontSize + d/1;
    var letter = letters[counter];
    var stepSize = textWidth( letter, fontSize );

    if (d > stepSize) {
      var angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y-position.y, mouse.x-position.x);

      context.font = fontSize + "px garamond-premier-pro";

      context.save();
      context.translate( position.x, position.y);
      context.rotate( angle );
      context.fillText(letter,0,0);
      context.restore();

      counter++;
      if (counter > letters.length-1) {
        counter = 0;
      }

    //console.log (position.x + Math.cos( angle ) * stepSize)
      position.x = position.x + Math.cos(angle) * stepSize;
      position.y = position.y + Math.sin(angle) * stepSize;

      }
  }     
}

function distance( pt, pt2 ){

  var xs = 0;
  var ys = 0;

  xs = pt2.x - pt.x;
  xs = xs * xs;

  ys = pt2.y - pt.y;
  ys = ys * ys;

  return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}

function mouseDown( event ){
  mouse.down = true;
  position.x = event.pageX;
  position.y = event.pageY;

  document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
}

function mouseUp( event ){
    mouse.down = false;
}

function doubleClick( event ) {
  canvas.width = canvas.width; 
}

function textWidth( string, size ) {
  context.font = size + "px garamond-premier-pro";

  if ( context.fillText ) {
    return context.measureText( string ).width;
  } else if ( context.mozDrawText) {
    return context.mozMeasureText( string );
  }

 };

init();
```

But instead of having the user click and drag to draw things on the canvas, it would be great if this could happen either automatically creating random lines with text, or even better, just by moving the mouse around the canvas (without actually clicking to produce the text animation paths). A touch / mobile friendly solution would also be preferable.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: For this to work for on `mousemove`, you just need to delete `if ( mouse.down )` statement in draw function.

Comment: You should include your code here, not just a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code modified to work on mousemove or touchmove without requiring mousedown to initialize the drawing: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/B2j5P/

The modifications are straightforward:

```
// add a touchmove event listener and point it toward the handleMove event handler

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);

// set the initial state of mouse.down to true instead of false

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, down:true}

// disable (or remove) resetting mouse.down to false in the mouseup event handler

function mouseUp( event ){
//    mouse.down = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch: This works like a charm, although not properly on mobiles / tablets (not an issue for me at the moment, as I am delivering a pared-down experience for mobiles anyway). Is there a way, though, of having this animation happening at the background of a transparent png image, so that it looks like the writing is BEHIND  the image?

Comment: Sure. Just use CSS to position your canvas directly under an img element.  Then set the img element's point-events property to none so the canvas underneath receives all the mouse events. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to use different events, i think this could do the trick.

Use "mouseover" event instead of the "mousedown" event. (I hope it also has pageX/Y information)

There are also special touch events you can use. http://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/touch-events.html